# Unable to download latest VimService.dll file

Tags: vmware, vsphere

I have VimService2005 and VimService2005.XmlSerializers in my project but that is not working since it is old version.So I am trying to download the latest version of these files but I couldn't find any download link for that.

Answer (score 0):

Step 4 of the following KB article reference a way to build your own: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/87402

```
csc /t:library /out:VimService2005.dll VimService.cs
```

Comment: than how to build VimService2005.XmlSerializers.dll